# AC6 eclipse - problem with running an example blinker using libopencm3

Tags: stm32, stm32f1, libopencm3

I'm having a problem with testing example of code for STM32F103 from libopencm3.
I included a libopencm3 in directory with inc files, and added inc directory to "Path and Symbols".  I get an error like no file or directory, even though i have file "libopencm3/stm32/common/rcc_common_all.h" in directory inc. What i'm doing wrong?

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

Comment: If you added the `libopencm3` dir to your include path then your `#include` file's path should start after the included dir i.e. `stm32/common/rcc_common_all.h`. If you want to keep `libopencm3` in the include directive then add `libopencm3`'s parent dir to the include path

Comment: i added "inc" directory as include, and inside there is libopencm3, so i don't think thats the problem

Comment: hmmm yeah you're right. Could you post the compiler output from the console window

Comment: https://pastebin.com/g77E5gNb

Comment: That's the compiler output for `BlinkTest0`. Are the structures of both projects the same? Also, according to the include flags, `libopencm3` isn't a directory inside `inc`: `-I"/niko2/SzkicownikiEclipse/BlinkTest0/inc" -I"/niko2/SzkicownikiEclipse/BlinkTest0/libopencm3"`